# Jar file not executing

Tags: jar

I am having a problem, I run my jar file but nothing happens, not even an error, it just returns to the cmd line where I started. the java code is ok because it works fine in netbeans on the machine i created it on, what is missing from the machine I am actually running it on? help please

Comment: How are you trying to execute it? I suggest copy-pasting how you're executing it and what happens next.

Comment: Might also help to post your MANIFEST file as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javaw(java's "consoleless" version) instead of java and you print the answers with:

```
System.out.println(String stringToPrint);
```

or with

```
System.out.print(String stringToPrint);
```

You won't have anything printed on the screen because javaw won't print anything, so try execute it like this:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

If this is not what you are looking for, sorry.